# Definition of Phase Noise

Tags: noise-spectral-density

I'm confused with the definition of phase noise. I'm referring to [this](http://www.umbc.edu/photonics/Menyuk/Phase-Noise/Vig_IEEE_Standard_1139-1999%20.pdf) IEEE document.
A noisy oscillator output is \$v(t) = A\sin(\omega t + \phi)\$, where phi is random phase deviation. I assumed no amplitude noise.  So carrier power is \$ P = \frac{A^2}{2*R_L}\$.

I can find the \$\phi\$, in radians and compute its onesided power spectral density with periodogram in matlab. Thus, I have \$S_\phi\$ in rad\$^2\$/hz.

Now, the IEEE document says, phase noise is defined as one half of \$S_\phi\$, but also says its unit is dbc/hz. Should not we dividing \$S_\phi\$ with P to get dbc/hz, but then \$S_\phi\$ unit is rad\$^2\$/hz not power, i.e. P is in Watts?

How can I correctly compute single side band phase noise spectrum in dbc/hz from \$S_\phi\$ which is in rad\$^2\$/hz?

Edit: the document I posted is old (1999). [This](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?arnumber=6581834&filter=AND(p_Publication_Number:6581832)) is the active one. But still, my understanding seems to be correct.

Comment: Instead of calculating the power spectral density of the phase phi  you should be calculating the power spectral density of the Noise surrounding the carrier resulting from the phase deviations.  Phi is a time domain parameter while the carrier power is described in the frequency domain. No wonder you get confused !

Comment: If I understand it correctly, that would be equal to half of s_phi, one sided power spectrum of instantaneous phase deviation. So I don't have to divide s_phi to carrier power, phase noise is simply half of what I mistakenly computed (s_phi). Am I right?

Comment: I don't think so because you need to convert that phase into frequency through a sin(x) function. If you search for them you should be able to find matlab examples with phasenoise. Have a look at those for some ideas.

Comment: I see. That's why document says L(f) is approximation. sin(x) = x when x is small.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I resolved my confusion, I am posting how I understand it as an answer:

\$ L(f) = \frac{S_\phi(f)}{2}\$;
\$ S_\phi(f)\$ : One-sided spectral density of the phase deviation
\$L(f)\$: One-half of the phase instability

From the RF spectrum, one can compute \$L(f)\$ by computing noise power around the carrier in dbc/hz giving \$\sin(\phi)\$. Since \$\phi\$ is small, \$\sin(\phi) = \phi\$, you got the spectrum of phase noise. So one does not need to compute phase deviations to compute phase noise.